# Как убрать появление блока при начале печати, и сделать, чтобы он был виден сразу?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть форма:

```
<textarea id="textarea" maxlength="25"></textarea><div id="textareaFeedback"></div>
```

И скрипт, который отображает, сколько символов осталось:

```
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        var maxLength = $('#textarea').attr('maxlength');
        $('#textarea').keyup(function()
        {
            var curLength = $('#textarea').val().length;
            $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, maxLength));
            var remaning = maxLength - curLength;
            if (remaning < 0) remaning = 0;
            $('#textareaFeedback').html(remaning + ' осталось символов');
            if (remaning < 10) // когда менять цвет
            {
                $('#textareaFeedback').addClass('warning')
            }
            else
            {
                $('#textareaFeedback').removeClass('warning')
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Как сделать, чтобы количество символов выводилось сразу, а не после начала печати в форме?

Comment: Изначально ведь 0 символов? Вот и пропишите в блок вывода максимальное кол-во

Comment: Не обязательно ноль. Дело в том, что в поле текст из базы выводится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть варианты, что поле не будет изначально пустое, то просто в самом начале проверяем сколько символов есть и отнимаем это число от максимально допустимого. [Примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/QaWJz/3/).

P.S. (*совет по-ходу*) Ваш код хорошо бы оптимизировать.

Comment: Ну дело в том, что поле изначально пустое. А потом уже после заполнения используется для редактирования.

Comment: Что-то вы меня совсем запутали. Вы пробовали мой вариант в действии? Пусть оно будет пустое, кто ж против? В этом случае будет максимальное кол-во символов.

Comment: Да я сам себя запутал уже. Спасибо за помощь. Это то, что нужно.